# CASE WHEN condition1 THEN result1 does not work

Tags: flink-sql

I am running flink sql in flink version 1.12.0 and batch mode,

```
select app_id, count(case cnt when 1 then 1 end ),  count(case cnt > 1 then 1 end ) from xxx
```

get result below:

```
xception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.SqlParserException: SQL parse failed. Encountered "then" at line 1, column 72.
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you missed `when` keyword in your SQL, the syntax should be:case when condition then ... end.

```
select app_id, count(case cnt when 1 then 1 end ),  count(case when cnt > 1 then 1 end ) from xxx
```